# HTML to XML Conversion XSLT

Tags: html, xml, xslt

Can you please help me in converting the below HTML to XML using XSLT mapping.

Input HTML:

```
<html><head></head><body>Array
(
    [Value] =&gt; 123
    [Head] =&gt; 456
    [Description] =&gt; Array
        (
            [1] =&gt; ABC
            [2] =&gt; DEF
            [3] =&gt; GHI
        )
    [Price] =&gt; Array
        (
            [1] =&gt; 123
            [2] =&gt; 456
            [3] =&gt; 789
        )
    [Quantity] =&gt; Array
        (
            [1] =&gt; 
            [2] =&gt; 
            [3] =&gt; 
        )
)</body></html>
```

[Input HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkqwF.jpg)

Expected XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<aa>
<Value>123</Value>
<Head>456</Head>
<Lines>
<Description>ABC</Description>
<Price>123</Price>
<Quantity></Quantity>
</Lines>
<Lines>
<Description>DEF</Description>
<Price>456</Price>
<Quantity></Quantity>
</Lines>
<Lines>
<Description>GHI</Description>
<Price>789</Price>
<Quantity></Quantity>
</Lines>
</aa>
```

[Output XML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLM6m.jpg)

Value and Head will appear just once. 
Whereas the array of Value, Description and Quantity may be multiple. And I need to group all 1s , 2s and so on inside the tags.
Please help.

Comment: At [so] you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/)**.

Comment: Although, strictly speaking, the input document is HTML, what you are effectively trying to do is parse a single piece of text, because that is how XSLT will view the contents of your `body` tag. You'll need to use at least XSLT 2.0 to have any chance of this, and even then it will be very complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below code in **XSLT 2.0**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//body"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="body">
        <xsl:variable name="temp">
            <xsl:analyze-string select="text()" regex="\[(.+)\] =&gt; (.*)">
                <xsl:matching-substring>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="matches(regex-group(1), '^[0-9]+$')">
                            <Array name="{regex-group(1)}"><xsl:value-of select="regex-group(2)"/></Array>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:element name="{regex-group(1)}"><xsl:value-of select="regex-group(2)"/></xsl:element>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:matching-substring>
            </xsl:analyze-string>
        </xsl:variable>
        <aa>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$temp//Value"/>            
            <xsl:copy-of select="$temp//Head"/>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="$temp//Array" group-by="@name">
                <Lines>
                    <Description><xsl:value-of select="current-group()[1]"/></Description>
                    <Price><xsl:value-of select="current-group()[2]"/></Price>
                    <Quantity><xsl:value-of select="current-group()[3]"/></Quantity>
                </Lines>
            </xsl:for-each-group>            
        </aa>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<aa>
   <Value>123</Value>
   <Head>456</Head>
   <Lines>
      <Description>ABC</Description>
      <Price>123</Price>
      <Quantity/>
   </Lines>
   <Lines>
      <Description>DEF</Description>
      <Price>456</Price>
      <Quantity/>
   </Lines>
   <Lines>
      <Description>GHI</Description>
      <Price>789</Price>
      <Quantity/>
   </Lines>
</aa>
```